Problem writing the Jacobi equation $\nabla_X \nabla_X Y = R(X, Y)X$ in components
I am trying to write the Jacobi equation  $\nabla_X \nabla_X Y = R(X, Y)X$ in component form, but comparing to the expression in the book I am following there seems to be a sign problem. I have redone the calculation many times and it is the same. It is an important equation that is used many times later in the book. Is there really a typo (actually several since it is used like that all the time later) in the book? Otherwise what am I doing wrong?
This is on section 4.3 of An Introduction to Mathematical Relativity by Natario. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.02855
You can see the context below
$\nabla_X(\nabla_X (Y^iE_i))=R(X,Y^iE_i)X$
The LHS is just $=\nabla_X(\nabla_X (Y^iE_i))=\ddot Y^i E_i$
Since $X$ is unit timelike and a basis vector. $X=X^0E_0$, with $X^0=1$, the RHS is
$R(X,Y^iE_i)X=Y^iR^\mu_{\nu\alpha\beta}X^\nu (E_i)^\alpha X^\beta E_\mu$
$= Y^i R^\mu_{0\alpha 0}X^0 (E_i)^\alpha X^0 E_\mu$
$= Y^i R^\mu_{0 \alpha 0}(\delta_i^\alpha) E_\mu$
$=Y^i R^\mu_{0 i 0} E_\mu=Y^j R^i_{0 j 0} E_i=-Y^j R^i_{0 0 j} E_i$
So we have  $\ddot Y^i E_i=-Y^j R^i_{0 0 j} E_i$
or $\ddot Y^i =-Y^j R^i_{0 0 j} $
But in the book there is no "-"sign.



Curvature tensor in roughly half of all text books are negative of the definition of curvature tensor in the other half of text books... Watch out!

@Yuval  The book uses this: $R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z.$ Or in components: $R_{\alpha \beta ,, \nu}^{\mu} = dx^{\mu} \left( R(\partial_{\alpha}, \partial_{\beta})\partial_{\nu} \right) = \partial_{\alpha} \Gamma_{\beta \nu}^{\mu} - \partial_{\beta} \Gamma_{\alpha \nu}^{\mu} + \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu} \Gamma_{\gamma \nu}^{\gamma} - \Gamma_{\beta \gamma}^{\mu} \Gamma_{\alpha \nu}^{\gamma}.$

@Yuval Shouldn't the sign be hidden inside the $R^i_{00j}$ components? Since I am not writing the definition with the Cristoffel symbols I can't see it. I mean I believe that unless I evaluate the $R^i_{00j}$  components explicitly I wouldn't see the sign , would I?

Therefore I think the sign convention is irrelevant here

1). In your computation, it seems you were using the parallel field $E^\mu$ as a coordinate vector - because you put superscript $\mu$ in the curvature $R$, I don't think one can do this. 2). Your notation of curvature seems to be different from the quoted book: In your comment above, if you take index $\alpha$ to be the same as $\beta$, the curvature $R$ would be $0$; in particular, $R_{00j}^i$ would be $0$. So apparently in the quoted book it is a different definition (basically just that he and you are placing the same index at different positions).
